# HTML textbox input pattern 0000000-0000

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, frontend

Basically I have an HTML textbox and the user enters digits.
What I want is to automatically put a - after the 7th digit
Basically have this pattern:

0000000-0000

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control width-160" name="value" required maxlength="10"/>
```

I'm pretty sure I need to use a regex for this, but can I use it directly in HTML or do I need some jQuery ?

Comment: You know you need regex, but what have you tried so far?

Comment: check this [https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask)

Comment: hey why you down vote my answer it works fine

Comment: You don't need to use jQuery.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `jquery.mask` for this

More info [Here](https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/)

Usage:

```
<input type="text" class="phone" name="value"/>

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.phone').mask('0000000-0000');
});
```

See it here live https://jsfiddle.net/n0oeu3p2/

Comment: Amazing! Very easy to use. I choose this as my answer!

Answer (score 2):

Try with [`slice()`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjx38fox_HTAhUJuI8KHUA3AVYQFggmMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3schools.com%2Fjsref%2Fjsref_slice_string.asp&usg=AFQjCNGj4ZJADahkdFk8napkEOQPtZv_Lg) and change the `input length` is `11`

```js
$('input').on('input',function(){
var str = $(this).val().replace('-','');
if(str.length > 7)
$(this).val(str.slice(0,7)+'-'+str.slice(7,str.length))

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="form-control width-160" name="value" required maxlength="11" />
```

Comment: There is no reason at all to use jQuery for this. Input is not restricted to digits and trying to edit the part before the "-" makes the input almost unusable.

Comment: Good answer but I'll go with Ambrish's one because of @RobG's observation. Thanks to you both!

Answer (score 0):

```html
<form action="javascript:alert('Corect!');">
  <input type="text" pattern="\d{7}-\d{4}" title="Should be of the format 0000000-0000"/>
</form>
```

Done! Only with html and regexp

Comment: you must be directly hitting enter without typing anything

Comment: It doesn't matter what I enter, I always get "Corect!".

Comment: your browser don't support html5

Comment: If lack of support for a particular feature means a browser "doesn't support HTML5" then likely all browsers in use are in the same boat. How many support every type of input element and all their features? ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Without the need to use any external library, you can use `onkeyup` event and just test if we type the  7th character append `-` to the value.

Here's what you will need:

```
var changeIt = function changeIt(input) {
  if (input.value.length === 7) {
    input.value = input.value + "-";
  }
}
```

**Demo:**

Here's a working Snippet:

```js
var changeIt = function changeIt(input) {
  if (input.value.length === 7) {
    input.value = input.value + "-";
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control width-160" name="value" required maxlength="12" onkeyup="changeIt(this)" pattern="[0-9]{7}-[0-9]{4}" />
```

And use `[0-9]{7}-[0-9]{4}` too as a regex in the `pattern` HTML attribute to make sure your input value matches the Regex `0000000-0000`.